# Dynamically apply formula to x number of columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

By using a variable x which is a positive integer, is it possible to apply a formula x number of times in a given column, without hardcoding each individual cell using a formula such as `=IF(COLUMN(A1)<X, formula, "")`?

The behaviour would be similar to `=TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(X))`, which populates x number of cells with increasing integers, except I would like to populate the cells with a formulas that are dependent upon the previous cells value.

**Example**

To help understand the question, below is a practical example using compound interest showing what I would like to happen.

Using the formula,

```
=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(B2, 1, YEAR(DATE(B1,1,1))))
```

with values such as B1=2021 and B2=5, I can choose the number of years to display by changing B2.

To calculate each year’s value, with the values compounding monthly, I can use the formula `= A7 * (1 + $B$3/12) ^ 12` with values such as B3=20% and A7=The previous year’s value.

Using the example values given above, and a starting value of £20,000, I get the below results.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start Year | 2021 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Number of years | 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Interest | 20% |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Starting Value | £20000 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | Start | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 |
| 7 | £20,000.00 | £24,387.82 | £29,738.29 | £36,262.61 | £44,218.30 | £53,919.40 |

When I change B2 from 5 to another value, e.g. 10, the years automatically populate 10 columns with the correct values.

**What I would like to happen**, as well as the years populating 10 columns, is the formula calculating the compound interest to automatically populate the 10 columns. Does anybody know any functions that might help or maybe there is an alternative way to achieve a similar result?

Thanks in advance, I hope the question is clear to understand.

Comment: BTW: `=TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(X))` can be rewritten to `=SEQUENCE(,X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the years:

```
=SEQUENCE(,B2, B1)
```

No need for Transpose

Then in B7 put:

```
= A7 * (1 + $B$3/12) ^ (12*SEQUENCE(,$B$2))
```

[image]